# Using Paraview to create RenderViews of the same size

Tags: python, visualization, paraview

This is a problem on using Paraview.
I'd like to create RenderViews with same square Scriptly. The set up I want is like below(This is by brutal force).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mOUn.jpg

CreateRenderView() Only gives RenderViews with below Shapes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI6E5.jpg

Anyone knows some tips ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I want to create square-shape renderviews under commandline.
The purpose to do this is to show all my data in a chessboard form.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [Comparative Views](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/comparativeViews.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, comparative views does [not support visibility](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/comparative-visualization-visibility/5561) currently.